# how to get the date into string format by passing date like-01/09/2016

Tags: javascript

I want to convert Date to string format with the day name and month name like ,if am passing date like 01/09/2016 then it should be got render like day name of 1st September like Thursday 01,September 2016,the toughest task is to get day name of date.so how can i achieve this?

Comment: Do you want the final result as `Thursday 1 September 2016`? Please specify in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that very easily with JavaScript. Try the following snippet:

```
var d = new Date("2016-09-01");
console.log(d.toDateString());
```

The output is:

> Thu Sep 01 2016

Comment: when you run it, it will give previous date.

Comment: Did you even try that? I'm checking that and it's giving the desired result.. Share the result you get..

Comment: i'm getting wed 31 august 2016. i run it in jsfiddle, here is no option to upload image on comments.

Comment: Can you share jsfiddle link?

Comment: It's showing the same output to me.. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122397/discussion-between-yash-and-sujeet-sinha).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var s = '2016/09/01';//this may be user entered string
    var d = new Date(s);
    var n = d.toString();
    console.log(n);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following re-tunes `Thursday 1 September 2016` when the following string is passed `'2016-09-01'`.

Please note the full name of the week `Thursday` is returned and not only and abbreviation like `Thu`;

```js
(function() {
  var dateFormat = function(ourDate) {
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],  
    weekDays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
    date = new Date(ourDate),
    year = date.getFullYear(),
    indexMonth = date.getMonth(),
    dayWeek = date.getDay(),
    day = date.getDate();
return weekDays[dayWeek] + ' ' + day + ' ' + months[indexMonth] + ' ' + year;
  };
  console.log(dateFormat('2016-09-01'));
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The format that you require dd/mm/yyyy is not natively supported you need to use something like momentjs to parse various different formats and then you can use toString as suggested

Answer (score 0):

javascript native date object can be constructed from string date. But it support 'mm/dd/yyyy' format. So first convert your date format in 'mm/dd/yyyy' format. Then you can construct javascript date object. After that you can use getDay and getMonth function to get day of week and month.

```js
function getDayOfDate (date){ 
  var arr = date.split('/'); 
  var newFormat=arr[1]+"/"+arr[0]+"/"+arr[2];
  var date = new Date(newFormat);
  return date.getDay();
}
```

the above function will return value from 0-6. You can use switch case to print day of week.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the datetime

```
Date.prototype.Format = function() {
   var weekday = new Array(7);
   weekday[0]=  "Sunday ";
   weekday[1] = "Monday ";
   weekday[2] = "Tuesday ";
   weekday[3] = "Wednesday ";
   weekday[4] = "Thursday ";
   weekday[5] = "Friday ";
   weekday[6] = "Saturday ";
   var weekday = weekday[this.getDay()];

   var day = this.getDay();

  if(day === 1)
     day += day + "st"
  else day+= "th"


  var months = new Array(12); 
  months[0]=  " January ";
  months[1] = " February ";
  months[2] = " Mars ";
  months[3] = " April";
  months[4] = " May ";
  months[5] = " June ";
  months[6] = " July ";
  months[7] = " August ";
  months[8] = " September ";
  months[9] = " October ";
  months[10] = " November ";
  months[11] = " December ";

  var month = months[this.getMonth()] 

  return weekday + day + month + this.getFullYear();

}; 

var d = new Date();

console.log(d.Format());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using below code, you get date string as you mentioned.

in some cases, you get previous date than the date you entered in the
 `var d = new Date("2016-09-01");` is due to `Eastern Daylight Time`.
so , this how you get exact date string format `enter code

```
var doo = new Date("2011-09-24");
console.log(new Date(doo.getTime() + doo.getTimezoneOffset()*60000));
```

here, is fiddle link : [pressme](https://jsfiddle.net/yashsoni789/4cuvsu3s/)